# 2D object array - replace object of array when reference copy is passed

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have a 2D object array, which represents a clickable editor in HTML (Tile editor). Each array object holds information such as which image to show.

```
interface Tile {
   id: number,
   image: string,
   category?: number
   skin?: string
   schema?: string
}


tileEditor = 
 [ row: {Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile},
   row: {Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile},
   row: {Tile, Tile, Tile, Tile} ]
```

HTML:

```
 <table>
    <tr *ngFor="let rows of tileEditor">
      <td *ngFor="let cell of rows.row" (mousedown)="canvasDown(cell)">
       <img src="{{ cell.image }}" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Result:

TS:

```
getTileObjectInit(){
   var obj =  {
   id: ''
   image: ''
   category: ''
   skin: ''
   schema: ''
}

tileEditor = 
 [ row: {this.getTileObjectInit(), this.getTileObjectInit(), this.getTileObjectInit(), this.getTileObjectInit()},
   row: {this.getTileObjectInit(), this.getTileObjectInit(), this.getTileObjectInit(), this.getTileObjectInit()},
   row: {this.getTileObjectInit(), this.getTileObjectInit(), this.getTileObjectInit(), this.getTileObjectInit()} ]

selectedTile: Tile

setSelectedTile(_tile: Tile) { this.selectedTile = _tile; }

canvasDown(tile: Tile) {
   tile.id = this.selectedTile.id
   tile.image = this.selectedTile.image
   if ("category" in this.selectedTile)
      tile.category = this.selectedTile.category
   else
      tile.category = ''
   if ("skin" in this.selectedTile)
      tile.skin = this.selectedTile.skin
   else
      tile.skin = ''
   if ("schema" in this.selectedTile)
      tile.schema = this.selectedTile.schema
   else
      tile.schema = ''
}
```

I initialized the tileEditor with empty dummy Tiles, which I would populate on click.

However, canvasDown shows the problem. I would like to simply replace the clicked Tile object with the selected Tile object. But I don't know how, as I just pass a copy of the object's reference. Therefore I must update the element values one by one (which is painful especially as I have optional values), as demonstrated in the `canvasDown(tile: Tile)` function.

In other words, I want my `canvasDown(tile: Tile)` function to work like this:

```
 canvasDown(tile: Tile) {
     tile = this.selectedTile
  }
```

But to replace the actual Tile object in my tileEditor and not the reference copy.

Can this be achieved somehow? (I'm using Angular 8)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to make this type of data**

```
getTileObjectInit(){
   return {
   id: '',
   image: '',
   category: '',
   skin: '',
   schema: ''
 }
}

tileEditor = 
 [ {row: [this.getTileObjectInit(), this.getTileObjectInit(), this.getTileObjectInit(), this.getTileObjectInit()]},
   {row: [this.getTileObjectInit(), this.getTileObjectInit(), this.getTileObjectInit(), this.getTileObjectInit()]},
   {row: [this.getTileObjectInit(), this.getTileObjectInit(), this.getTileObjectInit(), this.getTileObjectInit()]} ]
```

**How to Convert Object into array ?**

```
this.tileEditor.forEach(e => e.row = Object.values(e.row));
//Object.values() is returning the array of value of object. without key.
```

**Also another way to Convert your Object to array**

```
this.tileEditor.forEach(e => e.row = Object.keys(e.row).map(key => e.row[key]));
// Here, Object.keys() is returning the array of object's key,
// than .map() function is mapping data and it is getting by key of object
```

Now, that is convert your tileEditor.row object into Array. and you are getting above given result by me. then you can access your data in `*ngFor` loop

**After making this type of data You can access image in html like your html code that is given below**

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let rows of tileEditor">
      <td *ngFor="let cell of rows.row" (mousedown)="canvasDown(cell)">
       <img src="{{ cell.image }}" />
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```